# Syntax for passing props to stateless component

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I am using `inject` and `observer` in a stateless component and I am confused about the syntax for passing down some of the props from the parent component. Here is the parent component:

```
 <MenuItem>
        {cart.getItemsInCart.map((item, index) => {
              return <CartItem key={index}
                               item={item}
                     />
                })}
 </MenuItem>
```

Here is the child component `CartItem`:

```
const CartItem = inject("cart")(observer (({cart}) => {
  return (
      <div></div>
   )
}))
```

How do I access the `item` props being passed down inside my stateless component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used MobX, but the convention for higher-order components (such as `inject` and `observer`)  is to [pass any props on to the wrapped components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html#convention-pass-unrelated-props-through-to-the-wrapped-component), so in this case, you should be able to access `item` like so:

```
const CartItem = inject("cart")(observer (({cart, item}) => {
  return (
      <div></div>
   )
}))
```